# using php class and function for echoing common html

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ok I am learning php and trying out classes and functions.  Currently I have multiple pages where it has the same menu bar and user info so I decided to create a class Common and a function menu to load user info and echo info and menu content.  For some reason it is not displaying anything help?

```
class Content {
    public function menu($userid) {
        require_once("../class/class1.php");
        echo '<div id="logo"></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        echo '<div id="user">Welcome ';

        $db = new MySQL();
        $user = new User();
        $sql = $db->sql($user->loadUser($userid));

        if ($db->num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            while ($row = $db->fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
require_once("content.php");
$content = new Content();
echo $content->menu($userid);
```

when running in localhost i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\orbecargo\class\sql.php on line 3
```

that file is:

```
class MySQL
{
private $conexion;
private $total_consultas;

public function MySQL(){
    if(!isset($this->conexion)){
        $this->conexion = (mysql_connect("server","username","password")) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("database",$this->conexion) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_set_charset('utf8',$this->conexion);
    }
}
}
```

the weird thing is that other pages work perfectly...
and I removed the

```
echo $content->menu($userid);
```

and still nothing

Comment: Activate errors with function error_reporting(E_ALL) and watch if some errors are reported. Btw as you have written echo $content->menu($userid) it's wrong because you aren't returning anything (return keyword). you are ECHOING (printing in the page) strings. So you must do only $content->menu($userid) in this case.

Comment: i just added the error message and removed the echo but in localhost i get that error not online :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $content->menu($userid);
```

menu() does not return anything

remove the echo before the menu(); to

```
require_once("content.php");
$content = new Content();
$content->menu($userid);
```

Comment: did that but still nothing the file that is trying to call that is in another folder can that be it?

i have:
folder1/htmlfile.php
folder2/content.php

Comment: You need to make sure the path is correct. If in doubt USE absolute path. That might be it, the include_once() is not actually including the file. Switch to require_once() it will generate an error if the file is not found.

Comment: actually it was not only that but also inside my class I was including a file before the "class Mysql" declare